# div with swf inside and z-index : firefox mac bug

Tags: html, css, flash, firefox, actionscript-2

I've got a problem with firefox for mac and z-index.
I've got  3 div: header, wrapper and footer; inside of them i've got 3 swf header.swf, wrapper.swf and footer.swf.
This is the code:

```
<div id="header">
 <div id="navigation">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var fo = new FlashObject("fla/head.swf", "top", "960", "118", "7", "#fff", true);
   fo.addVariable("quality", "best"); 
   fo.addVariable("scale", "noscale"); 
   fo.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
   fo.write("navigation");
  </script>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="flashContent" class="home">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var fo = new FlashObject("fla/home.swf", "top", "1660", "840", "7", "#fff", true);
   fo.addVariable("quality", "best"); 
   fo.addVariable("scale", "noscale"); 
   fo.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
   fo.write("flashContent");
  </script>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="footer" class="fHome">
 <div id="news">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var fo = new FlashObject("fla/footer.swf", "top", "960", "130", "7", "#292929", true);
   fo.addVariable("quality", "best"); 
   fo.addVariable("scale", "noscale"); 
   fo.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
   fo.write("news");
  </script>
 </div>
</div>
```

and this is the css code:

```
body {overflow-x:hidden}
#header {position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; background:url(../img/bkgHeader.jpg) top left repeat-x; width:100%; height:118px; text-align:center; z-index:50}
#navigation {width:960px; height:118px; margin:0 auto;}
#wrapper {background:#fff; position:absolute; top:60px; left:0px; width:100%; height:840px; text-align:center; z-index:1}
#news {width:960px; height:130px; margin:0 auto;}
#flashContent {width:1660px;margin:0 auto;}
.home {height:840px;}
#footer {position:absolute; left:0px; background:url(../img/bkgFooter.jpg) bottom left repeat-x; width:100%; height:130px; text-align:center; z-index:3}
.fHome {top:880px;}
```

the problem is that wrapper div dont work good with zindex and cant stay below the header.
So rollover and rollout actions doesnt work!

pls help!

Answer (score 0):

for z-index also negative numbers are allowed.... maybe can help? Or give an extremely high z-index value to the other guys!

Comment: i've found that firefox on mac have bug with z-index, so change the number of z-index in css is not enought!